# Border not displayed in Outlook app but present in any web browser

Tags: html, outlook

I have a form that would be sent to an Outlook email. The same email when opened in a web browser displays all the borders, but not in the app. I have attached the code:

```
 <td width="100%">
    <form width="100%" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#35393d;">
        Corporation Number <input type="text" name="number" maxlength="10" style="width:5%;border-width: 1px ;border-style:solid;border-color:#000000;" value="%%CRPNUM%%">&nbsp; 
        Corporation Name <input type="text" name="name" style="border-bottom-width: 1px ;border-botttom-style:solid ;border-bottom-color:#000000;width:20%;border:none" value="%%CRPNAME%%">&nbsp;
        Accounting Month <input type="text" name="month" style="padding-bottom:15px;border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e5e5;" value="%%MONTH%%">
    </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be linked to the size of your windows / elements hiding the border ?

Outlook 2007/10/13 likes defined width per  - otherwise it interprets the width its own way.